# Defining JSON dynamically - can't find what I am doing wrong

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to put form content in a JSON dynamically.
It worked before, but after I added a extra layer (arrays in arrays) there seem to be something that I am doing wrong:

```
aJSON = {};
aJSON['properties'] = [];
aJSON['options'] = [];
aJSON['arrays'] = [];
$('input').each(function () {
    if($(this).attr('name') != undefined) {
        if($(this).attr('name').indexOf('[]') > -1) {
            if(aJSON['arrays'][$(this).attr('name')] == undefined) {
                aJSON['arrays'][$(this).attr('name')] = [];
            }
            if($(this).is(':checked')) {
                aJSON['arrays'][$(this).attr('name')][$(this).attr('value')] = 1;
            } else {
                aJSON['arrays'][$(this).attr('name')][$(this).attr('value')] = 0;
            }
        } else {
            aJSON['properties'][$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
        }
    }
});

$('select').each(function () {
    if($(this).attr('name') != undefined) {
        aJSON['properties'][$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    }
});
var array = getUrlVars();
aJSON['options']['type'] = array['type'];
aJSON['options']['id'] = array['id'];
aJSON['options']['view'] = pageSpecificVariables['view'];
```

The top 4 lines are just a tryout, I also tried:

```
aJSON = {'properties':[], 'options':[], 'arrays':[]}
```

But the only result I am getting is an object with empty arrays of properties, options and arrays.

Before I put all the values directly in aJSON and that worked perfectly.
But for categorizing, I need the 3 categories to exist.

Any idea why my values aren't written to the aJSON?

### EDIT

Added JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/abayob/pob32fs1/

Comment: Please show a testable example with HTML and event handlers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are trying to serialise a form.

Use jQuery's ***serializeArray*** function instead

```
var myform = $("#myform");
var data = JSON.stringify( myform.serializeArray() );
```

**Update**

Because you're trying to use `arrays` like `object-maps`

***Solution:*** http://jsfiddle.net/pob32fs1/8/

```
    var oJSON = {
        properties: {},
        options: {},
        arrays: {}
    };
    $('input[name]').each(function(){  
        var $el = $(this),
            value = $el.attr("value"),
            name = $el.attr('name');
        if(name.indexOf('[]') >= 0)
        {
            oJSON.arrays[name] = oJSON.arrays[name] || {};
            oJSON.arrays[name][value] = $el.is(':checked') ? 1 : 0;            
        } else {
            oJSON.properties[name] = $el.val();
        }
    });
    $('select[name]').each(function(){
        var $el = $(this);
        oJSON.properties[$el.attr('name')] = $el.val();
    });

    oJSON.options['type'] = 'user';
    oJSON.options['id'] = 1;
    oJSON.options['view'] = 'user-settings';
    console.log(oJSON);
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but it is not an answer to my question :)

Comment: Update to my answer. Plus you could refactor your code a little (see update).

Comment: Thanks for all the help. This is really informative!!

Comment: You're welcome. Updated it again, $el.is(':checked') refactored aswell

Comment: I was wondering if that would be faster? When you do it like my code. Does the script keep executing the same search every time I call for this? Or is it stored in memory anyway?

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand you. $('input[name]') and $('select[name]') queries are called every time - in other words the dom search is done every time. You could store them in variables if they never dynamically change.

Comment: The answer you gave me about performance means a lot! I found a way to measure the difference and it is pretty big: 1.6 to 1.17. So about 36% performance increase. Thanks a lot for this!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `name` and `value` attributes of your various inputs are strings, and not just numbers, you should be using nested *objects*, not nested arrays.  You're trying to use associative arrays, which are not available in JavaScript.

```js
var oJSON = {};

$('._save, .btn-success').click(function() {
  oJSON = {
    properties: {},
    options: {},
    arrays: {}
  };

  $('input').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('name') != undefined) {
      if ($(this).attr('name').indexOf('[]') > -1) {
        if (oJSON['arrays'][$(this).attr('name')] == undefined) {
          oJSON['arrays'][$(this).attr('name')] = {};
        }
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          oJSON['arrays'][$(this).attr('name')][$(this).attr('value')] = 1;
        } else {
          oJSON['arrays'][$(this).attr('name')][$(this).attr('value')] = 0;
        }
      } else {
        oJSON['properties'][$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
      }
    }
  });
  $('select').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('name') != undefined) {
      oJSON['properties'][$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    }
  });

  oJSON['options']['type'] = 'user';
  oJSON['options']['id'] = 1;
  oJSON['options']['view'] = 'user-settings';
  console.log(oJSON);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div id="tab-general" class="tab-pane active">
    <h4>Gebruikersnaam</h4>

    <input type="text" value="John Doe" name="username" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="J. Average">
    <h4>E-mailadres</h4>

    <input type="email" value="info@info.info" name="mailaddress" class="form-control" required="" placeholder="E-mail@adres.nl">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="password" name="password" minlength="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Nieuw wachtwoord">
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="password" name="password_retype" minlength="10" class="form-control" placeholder="Herhaal wachtwoord">
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="password" name="password_old" class="form-control margin-y-10" placeholder="Huidig Wachtwoord">
  </div>
  <div id="tab-sites" class="tab-pane">
    <h4>Websites</h4>

    <div id="site_container">
      <div class="checkbox block">
        <input name="sites[]" checked="" type="checkbox" value="0">
        <label>A</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox block">
        <input name="sites[]" checked="" type="checkbox" value="1">
        <label>B</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox block">
        <input name="sites[]" checked="" type="checkbox" value="2">
        <label>C</label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning _cancel">Annuleren</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-success _save">Opslaan</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I knew it had to be something simple: changing '[]' to '{}'. I just didn't see it!